# Print Chinese character in Python2 or Python3

Tags: python, utf-8, chinese-locale, python-3.6

Recently I've been studying Python, there is some differences between Py2 and Py3, and it's hard to understand them for new babies.

The shebang in the head is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

And when I want to print out the Chinese characters, things don't work out.

[image: why they appear as the 'utf-8' format, not the original ones]
even if I add the ".decode()" function in each sentence, they are just the same.

[image: the right way to show the characters]

When it comes to Python3, I got an error msg.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: it seems your console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell doesn't use `UTF-8` so Python can't convert it to `UTF-8` and it uses `ascii` which doesn't have China chars.

Comment: to print text you have to use `encode()` (or `encode('utf-8')`), not `decode()`. `decode()` is used to convert ie. `UTF-8` to `UNICODE` when you get text from keyboard, or from network/socket/file. `encode()` is used to convert `UNICODE` to `UTF-8` when you what to print or send by network/socket or save in file.

Comment: BTW: if you print list then Python uses `repr(...)` with every element on list to show you information usefull for debuging - ie. `u"\u7532"`. You have to concatenate elements from list to one string before you print it - ie. `print("".join(jiazi]))`

Comment: What doesn't work?